# Seasoning won't stick to baked potato chips

Tags: spices

I've been trying to make homemade baked potato chips, I have figured out everything, except how to get the seasoning to stick to the chips.  The recipe I'm using, calls for you to toss the chips in a bowl of seasoning right out of the oven. The seasoning is not sticking.

Comment: We need more info on how you are preparing this, especially what you are doing with oils/fats.

Comment: I imagine that baked chips will have a dry surface, so if your spices are also dry there is nothing for them to stick *to*. Fried chips obviously have oil on the surface which helps spices to adhere. Can you post more info about your recipe/process to help us see if there is an obvious 'fix'?

Comment: The recipe calls for soaking the chips in cold water for 30 minutes, then pat dry, placing on baking sheet, spritzing chips with  olive oil before baking, after baking crisp, toss in bowl with dry seasoning.

Comment: Do you mean chips (US) aka crisps (UK etc.), or chips (UK etc.) aka French Fries?  When the latter are seasoned it's usually before cooking.  The oil is important; we need more details on how/when that's applied.

Comment: US chips, the oil is just spritzed on, before baking.  My husband loves chips, but he had open heart surgery and has been told to eat a low fat and low sodium diet.  So I have been trying to find a healthy way to make chips for him.  He says the chips are nice and crunchy, they just need to be spicy.

Comment: @ChrisH I guessed US chips, because in the UK we don't call the fries 'potato chips' we just call them 'chips', we might at a pinch call the thin crunchy things 'potato crisps'. if we cook UK chips in the oven, we call then 'oven chips'. I trust that is as clear as mud.

Comment: @Spagirl I agree with all that, however I didn't assume that the OP was from either country

Comment: @ChrisH Didn't suggest you did. It was intended to be a faintly informative general aside, that's all.

Answer (score 5):

Since the potato slices are moist after cutting and before baking, [season them at this point](http://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/air-fried-potato-chips-530270) rather than afterwards. This will cause the seasoning to cling to the potato better, even after they have been dried in the oven.

Also, I have had good results using an "[Air Fryer](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=air%20fryer&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aair%20fryer)" (Which is technically not 'frying' but convection baking.)

Comment: I will try this. I did use a Air Fryer to begin with. But I found the chips stuck together.

Comment: over crowding can cause them to stick together, try smaller batches.

Comment: I will try this also.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make certain the herbs/spices are finely ground.

if they are too coarse, they will not stick to the chips.

Comment: I will try to grind them fine next time,  I just used them right from the bottles.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, grind the salt fine as dust, it will stick far better.

Answer (score 0):

Do the seasoning prior to baking.

Spices taste less harsh and easier to swallow after they've been exposed to the heat of the oven.